# Heroku and MongoDB Atlas - 5000ms Response time??? (MERN stack)

Tags: mongodb, heroku, mern

Have recently built a MERN stack application. For whatever reason I can't figure out, I'm getting a 5000ms response time and can't for the life of me figure out why.

The MongoDB atlas cluster and Heroku-hosted backend are both in the United States. MongoDB is on a $56 / month plan and Heroku is also on a $50 / month plan.

Anyone have any clues?

I've tried verifying that the two were based on the same continent. I had videos before that seemed to slow things down but not sure what the problem could be as I deleted those videos.

Comment: Hi, on the same both as you. On my end, it seems to be related to connection pool size. So, once a request takes time, it blocks all upcoming ones then it quickly ends up with response time > 5000. I was able to lower down this situation using maxPoolSize but it's hard to find the sweet spot between number of dynos & clusters.

Answer (score 0):

figured this out guys. turns out you shouldn't try to fetch over 30 full size (2.0mb) pictures with a single api request on page load. I made the wise move to compress my images before storing them lol